# Does Prolog have an "if and only if" operator?

Tags: prolog

I would normally write such a statement as two clauses, like this:

```
x :- y.
y :- x.
```

In Prolog, is there any concise way to write a statement like "if x then y, and vice-versa"?

In other words, is it possible to write "x if and only if y" as a single statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You said you would normally write *"p if and only if q"* (I will write *q <=> q* in the following) as

```
p :- q.
q :- p.
```

but that is only correct if

1. there are no other clauses for p and q
2. there are no variables involved

And under those circumstances, the code doesn't really say anything interesting, only that p and q are equivalent, but whether they are true or false is not stated.

If variables are involved, say

```
p(X) :- q(X).
q(X) :- p(X).
```

then the meaning is

```
forall X: p(X) <= q(X)  and  forall X': q(X') <= p(X')
```

which is the same as

```
forall X,X':  p(X) <= q(X)  and  q(X') <= p(X')
```

when what you actually wanted to say was

```
forall X:  p(X) <= q(X)  and  q(X) <= p(X)
```

---

On the other hand, as long as you have only a *single* clause for a predicate, then that clause alone can be read as an "if and only if".  For example

```
p(X,Y) :- q(X,Z).
```

means

```
forall X,Y  exists Z:  p(X,Y) <=> q(X,Z)
```

and if q/2 is defined elsewhere, then this is a sensible thing to write.  That way you can define aliases, projections, etc.

---

You haven't given any background to your question, but once you consider variables, it makes sense to ask "under which circumstances is p <=> q ?", where p and q defined arbitrarily.  Then you would like to write something like

```
p_iff_q(X) :- p(X) <=> q(X).
```

which, in plain Prolog, you'd have to rewrite into something like

```
p_iff_q(X) :- p(X),q(X) ; \+p(X),\+q(X).
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know not in swi-prolog.

On the other hand, you can write a small rewrite-predicate to automatically rewrite your program theory using the following small program:

```
:- dynamic([system:term_expansion/2]).

:- op(900, xfx, user:(:::)).

system:term_expansion(:::(H,T),[H :- T, T :- H]) :-
    callable(H),
    callable(T).
```

Then you can simply use

```
x ::: y.
```

Of course you can assign another operator than `:::`, you simply replace the operator definition (`op/3`) and `term_expansion/2` accordingly.

---

On the other hand, only when the the head and body are resolved before you call this, this won't yield to an infinite loop. Otherwise, the transformed program will loop infinitely. Prolog is not a real logic engine, it's merely logic programming: specifying a program in a logical syntax, not expressing a logical theory.

Comment: How is logic programming distinct from real "logic engines"? I haven't heard of this distinction before.

Comment: Prolog uses the SLD-paradigm: left-to-right depth-first evaluation with Negation as Finite Failure and Closed World Assumption. For instance answer set programming uses a different semantic (bottom-up, constructive negation, etc.)

Comment: If it's true that Prolog can't express logical theories, then are there other languages which can express them?

Comment: There are several languages, each with their own semantics and shortcomings. A quite complete software package for this is the IDP system we develop at our university. It supports full first-order logic. http://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/krr/software

Comment: That link appears to be broken now. Is a replacement available?

Comment: @AndersonGreen: yes [here](https://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/software/idp), will email our website admin... And an online IDE/RE can be found [here](http://adams.cs.kuleuven.be/idp/).

Comment: I'm trying to define predicates in the IDP programming language, similar to the ones in Prolog. Are any support forums available for the IDP system?

Comment: Hi, I am one of the maintainers of the IDP system. Currently we don't have a support forum, but you can send questions about IDP to krr-dev@cs.kuleuven.be and we will try to help you as best as we can

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to represent "if-and-only-if" rules in Prolog using [Constraint Handling Rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_Handling_Rules).

For example, in SWI-Prolog:

```
:- use_module(library(chr)).

:- chr_constraint class/2,species/2,animal/1,mammal/1,bird/1.

%X can be a member of only one species
species(X,X1),species(X,X2) <=> X1 = X2.

%X can be a member of only one class
class(X,X1),class(X,X2) <=> X1 = X2.

%X is a bird if and only if X is an animal and a pelican or a pigeon
bird(X) <=> animal(X),class(X,bird),(species(X,pelican);species(X,pigeon)).

%X is a mammal if and only if X is an animal
mammal(X) <=> animal(X),class(X,mammal),(species(X,cat);species(X,dog);species(X,bear)).
```